# Use smart pointers with Tensorflow C API objects in a class

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I would like to use an object that has specific deleter and constructor in a smart pointer.

The object is called: TF_Status - it is created with the function TF_NewStatus() and delete with the function TF_DeleteStatus().

When I want to use it with a smart pointer, I will initialize it like this:

`std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, void(*)(TF_Status*)> status(TF_NewStatus(), TF_DeleteStatus);`

However, when I want to use it as a class member, I do not want to create the object in the c'tor, because I have to set some values before. The problem is that there is no default c'tor for this kind of smart pointer.

Do you guys have any solutions?

Comment: I don't understand. So don't pass `TF_NewStatus()`, pass `nullptr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand correctly, you need something like this:

```
struct some_t
{
    some_t()
        : m_status(nullptr, TF_DeleteStatus)
    {}
    void later()
    {
        m_status.reset(TF_NewStatus());
    }
    std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, void(*)(TF_Status*)> m_status;
};
```

The unique_ptr becomes a zero pointer at construction time. Later you can create the `TF_Status` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a `unique_ptr` holding a null pointer first, and then reset this pointer with an actual `TF_Status`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// TF_*
struct TF_Status {};
TF_Status* TF_NewStatus() { std::cout << "\tNew TF_Status\n" ; return new TF_Status(); }
void TF_DeleteStatus(TF_Status* s) { std::cout << "\tDelete TF_Status\n"; delete s; }

#include <memory>

class C
{
    std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, decltype(TF_DeleteStatus)*> status;
public:
    C() : status(nullptr, TF_DeleteStatus) {}
    void acquire_status() {
        status.reset(TF_NewStatus());
    }
};

// test

int main()
{
    std::cout << "About to instantiate a C\n";
    C c;
    std::cout << "done\n";
    
    std::cout << "About to acquire_status\n";
    c.acquire_status();
    std::cout << "done\n";
}
```

#### Output

> ```
> g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
> About to instantiate a C
> done
> About to acquire_status
>   New TF_Status
> done
>   Delete TF_Status
> ```

Note that [`std::unique_ptr::reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) :

> Given `current_ptr`, the pointer that was managed by `*this`, performs the following actions, in this order:
>
> 1. Saves a copy of the current pointer `old_ptr = current_ptr`
> 2. Overwrites the current pointer with the argument `current_ptr = ptr`
> 3. If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object `if(old_ptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)`.

So you're safe even if your smart pointer contains an actual `TF_Status` when you invoke `reset()` on it.

([demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca00af81e845ca91))

Comment: A (better?) alternative would be to have a `std::optional` managed C object So you don't need to rely on the nullness of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a deleter class:

```
struct TF_Status;
void TF_DeleteStatus(TF_Status*);

struct TF_StatusDeleter { 
    void operator()(TF_Status* s) noexcept { TF_DeleteStatus(s); } 
};
```

And then:

```
using TF_StatusPtr = std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, TF_StatusDeleter>;
```

This way `TF_StatusPtr` can be default-initialized (no need to explicitly initialize this member in the constructor) and `sizeof(TF_StatusPtr) == sizeof(TF_Status*)`. `std::unique_ptr` uses empty base-class optimization for the deleter and hence a `TF_StatusDeleter` sub-object with no data members occupies 0 bytes.

Whereas `std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, void(*)(TF_Status*)>` is twice as big because each instance stores a pointer to same `TF_DeleteStatus` function, which is a waste.

Comment: Thanks!
How can I initialize the content of the pointer during the code, then? Is it: ```std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, TF_StatusDeleter> x = std::unique_ptr<TF_Status, TF_StatusDeleter>(TF_NewStatus());``` the best way?

Comment: @AmitN `x.reset(new TF_NewStatus);`

Comment: @AmitN https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset